# Stored Procedure instead of SqlBulkCopy

Tags: c#, ado.net

Inserting data from a csv file. How do I use a stored procedure instead of `SqlBulkCopy` to insert from datatable to database? Currently using:

```
 using (SqlBulkCopy sqlBulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(con))
 {
     sqlBulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "dbo.db";
     con.Open();
     sqlBulkCopy.WriteToServer(dt);
     con.Close();
 }
```

Comment: there is an even faster way to bulk insert data into a database via XML have you considered doing that..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `dt` is a `DataTable` you can "map" this to a `TABLE` type in SQL Server and pass it as a procedure parameter (`SqlDbType.Structured`).

Example: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675163%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: How do you view the  data in the user defined table in sql? Select * from doesn't work

Comment: In the procedure you can treat it like a table, it has no meaning outside